# Use event schedule and stored procedure to automatically average every hour MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-event

I have a database in Mysql Workbench about weather that updates every second. It contains temperature and wind speed. This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`temperature` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`wind_speed` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`humidity` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

I want to find the average temperature every hour and insert the result into a new table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table1` (
`idsea_state` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`dateavg` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`avg_temperature` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idsea_state`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

this is my coding to find average and insert the result into new table

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
(`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
SELECT `date` , avg(`temperature`)
FROM   `new_table`
GROUP BY DATE( date ), HOUR( date );
```

and this is my code for stored procedure

```
USE `test`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$ 
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()  
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `table1`
   (`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
  SELECT `date` , avg(`temperature`)
  FROM   `new_table`
  GROUP By DATE( date ), HOUR( date );
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

the problem is I want this coding average run automatically every hour, should I use stored procedure and event scheduler? 
Please help me, I don't know how to use event scheduler in Mysql Workbench.

Answer (score 5):

Run this in MySQL

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Add this to `my.cnf` so the scheduler remains enabled upon mysql restart

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON
```

Start the Event on the Next Hour, Make it Recurring Every Hour, Adjusting `WHERE` clause

```
CREATE EVENT hourly_temp_avg
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY HOUR
    STARTS DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL (HOUR(NOW())+1) HOUR
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
INSERT INTO `table1` (`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
SELECT `DATE` , avg(`temperature`)
FROM `new_table`
WHERE `date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

Masoud came up with the proper concept first. So, he gets +1 from me.

Comment: It was just this check, I was in the same scenario with my Procedure, its important to SHOW EVENTS\G; after turn it on and also check if yourEvent is created SHOW CREATE EVENT yourevent\G

Comment: For mysql 8, EVERY HOUR requires a number to it, so this should be EVERY 1 HOUR.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the event scheduler is on

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

and then create the event as below:

```
CREATE EVENT hourly_temp_avg
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
INSERT INTO `table1`
   (`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') , avg(`temperature`)
  FROM   `new_table`
  WHERE 
  `date` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()  - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:01') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00');
```

this event will run every hour and stores the past one hour avg in table1.

Comment: I would recommend that you not use the word "date" as a fieldname. It makes your code non-portable and, more importantly perhaps, makes debugging more difficult. Use "my_date" or "the_date" or similar.

Comment: you are certainly right. I just followed Tia naming convention to avoid confusion.

Comment: You don't need to format dates to strings: `WHERE date BETWEEN NOW()  - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND NOW()` would be fine (and avoiding unnecessary conversion back and forth).

Comment: `date` is in datetime format. if he creates the event on let's say 11:23:00 next one hour will be 12:23:00 (when the even will be executed). so the where clause will consider the time too. So I am trying to get the exact one hour avg (11:00:00 to 12:00:00) rather than 11:23:00 to 12:23:00

Comment: Date and datetime values are not stored in a string format. If you are trying to avoid selecting some values twice, you can use a including-excluding range (which is usually better than `BETWEEN` for this reason exactly). Something like: `WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND date <= NOW()`

Comment: Im not trying to avoid calculating a value twice. I am just trying to make the summary of exact one hour range and with exact i mean for example from 1 to 1:59 pm rather than say 1:48 pm to 2:47 PM. I hope i made myself clear :)

Comment: Oh disregard my previous comments. I have just read the question again and you are right, they want to group by the hour. I did not notice the first time. Your query is not what I'd have used, but it's a valid way to "truncate" to the hour.